What does Paul Birch mean by kg * s^-1 * kg^-1?
In Paul Birch's paper, Terraforming Venus Quickly he mentions a unit kg * s^-1 * kg^-1, which I interpreted as ($\frac{kg}{kg \cdot s} = \frac{1}{s}$). This is a valid unit, representing a rate. However, in this context he is talking about a mass throughput which could be achieved and mentions a value of 10^-5. This seems very low to me. Is it possible that this is a typo, or am I misunderstanding something?


Can't write an answer without reading more of the paper, but I read it as something like
"10^-5 kg of Hydrogen produced per second per kilogram used of something else". Depending on context this something else might be weight of machinery, weight of the "material from nearby moons" or something related.

@asdfex Yeah, I think that's what he's talking about... it's gas kg uplifted per dumped kg dropped.

@DarthPseudonym That wouldn't work - it would be kg / kg no matter what the rate is. Might be kilogram of the "orbital ring" though. And we seem to be talking about a fixed mass, not something that gets used up - due to the fact that the price mentioned in the next lines drops the longer it's running.

In the Ref 12 article, "Supramundane Planets", on page 179, he says...

In order to estimate the cost of such a procedure we note that the throughput of an orbital ring system is of the order its mass divided by a characteristic time, usually the orbital period. In the case of SupraJupiter a throughput of $~10^{-5}\ kg\ s^{-1}/\ kg$ could be achieved.

So what I think he's saying here is that every second, the orbital ring could process ${1\over10000}^{th}$ its own mass. By "process", I believe that he means: a) Harvest potential energy by moving some mass from a moon down to the planet's surface, and b) Use the harvested energy to move some gas from the planet's surface into an orbit around the planet (see Fig. 8 below).


Then in the case of terraforming Venus, I heard on SFIA values of around 10^20kg of hydrogen would have to be transported to Venus to convert all the CO2 into water and CO since CO2 + H2 -> CO + H20. Assuming that it takes 30 years = 946 080 000 seconds and an orbital ring can lift up 1/10000th of its mass every second, you would need an orbital ring with a mass of 1.057 * 10^15kg?

If true, and given Titania is $3.455\times10^{21}$ kg, then the ring would be around $3.0\times10^{-7}$ the mass of that moon. But, I didn't check any of Paul Birch's math. My answer just provides an interpretation of what he was probably trying to say.
